# How do I implement Redux to functional components that already have props?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to redux and I have ran into a problem. When I had my necessary redux configurations all set up(like connect,mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    dayPlanner: state.dayPlanner,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onMounted: (dayPlanner) => dispatch(createDayPlanner(dayPlanner)),
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage);
```

and then I placed the values to my functional component as the argument

```
const MainPage = ({onMounted, dayPlanner}) => {
....
}
```

the results work fine,meaning that both onMounted and dayPlanner that I defined have the expected value that I anticipated, but I found out that if I was to implement this on a component that already has props as an argument,my values turn into undefined

```
const MainPage = (props,{onMounted, dayPlanner}) => {
....
}
```

so I am not sure if it is because you're not supposed to implement it in a component that already rely on props or is there a way to fix my issue?

I found out that if I switched the arguments order like this

```
const MainPage = ({onMounted, dayPlanner},props) => {
    ....
}
```

my redux variables would work, but props would have error

maybe this is a concept on setting the arguments on functional components that I am not aware of, would like someone to help me explain , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, you are using functional components and if you are using functional components with redux, this is how you should access your props from the redux and the main prop object. Because you have to use the spread operator to get the rest.

```
const MainPage = ({onMounted, dayPlanner,...props}) => {
     console.log(props)
    ....
}
```

Then you can have both props and your redux props separately.

In case you need a reference for the spread operation to differentiate props. https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes

Comment: thank you.So I guess this was just some basic ES6 spread operator concept I need to be more familiar with...